# JNA how call a method from java in an Pointer received from dll?

Tags: java, pointers, dll, native, jna

I have a method in the dll which returns a pointer to an object

C code

```
basic_hash* getAlgorithmInstance( int algorithm )
```

object has the following methods:

```
void reset ();
void hash (const byte* data, uint64 size, vector_byte& hash).
```

how can I call the methods of this object?

I have an implementation which returns a pointer

java code

```
public interface LIB extends Library {
        LIB INSTANCE = (LIB ) Native.loadLibrary(
                (Platform.isWindows() ? "LIB " : "linuxLIB"), LIB.class);
        Pointer getAlgorithmInstance(int i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            LIB lib = LIB.INSTANCE;
            Pointer pointer = lib.getAlgorithmInstance(0);
            //pointer.reset(); //TODO how call?
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an "object" in `C`.  Your function is most likely returning a structure pointer (`struct*`).  Show us the definition of `basic_hash`, and look up the JNA references to `Callback` or "function pointer".

Comment: basic_hash - it's interface with next method: **void reset (); void partial (const byte* data, uint64 size); void finalize (vector_byte& hash); void hash (const byte* data, uint64 size, vector_byte& hash).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare callbacks for each function pointer.  Here's an example for "reset".

```
public class BasicHash extends Structure {
    public interface Reset extends Callback {
        public void invoke();
    }
    public Reset reset;
    public BasicHash() { }
    public BasicHash(Pointer p) { super(p); read(); }
}

BasicHash hash = mylib.getAlgorithmInstance(0);
hash.reset.invoke();
```

Comment: if I call I reset the VM falls, it falls dll curve or a wrong call?

Comment: `# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [HAL.dll+0x5524]`